# Relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, extern

I have a `C` driver file which declares an `extern` function in order to use it in my `asm` file. I am on a Windows 7 x64 machine.

I assembled the `asm` file with `NASM` with this command:

> nasm avxmain.asm -f win64 -o avxmain.o

Then I compiled the `C` file like this:

> gcc avxdriver.c -c -m64 -o avxdriver.o

Linking it all together, I ran:

> gcc avxdriver.o avxmain.o -o final

Here are the errors I am getting:

> avxmain.o:G:\Desktop\CPSC240:(.text+0x50): relocation truncated to
>   fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.bss'
>
> avxmain.o:G:\Desktop\CPSC240:(.text+0xb9): relocation truncated to
>   fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.data'
>
> avxmain.o:G:\Desktop\CPSC240:(.text+0xc2): relocation truncated to
>   fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.data'
>
> avxmain.o:G:\Desktop\CPSC240:(.text+0x14e): relocation truncated to
>   fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.bss'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

---

### `avxdriver.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern double avxdemo();

int main()
{
    double return_code = -99.9;
    printf("%s","This program will test for the presence of AVX (Advanced Vector Extensions) also known as state component number 2.\n");

    return_code = avxdemo();

    printf("%s %1.12lf\n","The value returned to the driver is ", return_code);
    printf("%s","The driver program will next send a zero to the operating system.  Enjoy your programming.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

### `avxmain.asm` file:

http://pastebin.com/CfnjbpXM

I posted it here because it is very long due to comments provided by the professor.

---

I have tried running the `-fPIC` and `-mcmodel=medium` option. I still get the same errors.
I'm completely lost and confused since this is the sample project I am supposed to run for my class. This subject is brand new to me. I've spent about half my day searching these errors and trying different things. I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried `default rel` in the asm code?

Comment: @harold Could you explain what that is? I am still brand new to assembly programming but taking steps to learn it.

Comment: Basically the equivalent of using `[rel label]` everywhere use used `[label]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that general x64 instructions do not allow direct 64-bit addresses in their encodings. There are two ways around this:

1. Use the `movabs rax, symbolNameHere` instruction to set `rax` to the address, then use `[rax]` to access data at that address.
2. Use `[rel symbolNameHere]` as the operand; this creates a PC-relative reference to `symbolNameHere`. It's encoded as a 32-bit signed offset from whatever `rip` will be when that instruction is executed.

Method 1 allows you to encode the absolute address in the instruction, whereas method 2 is smaller code (you can always do `lea rax, [rel symbolNameHere]` to get the same effect as method 1).

Comment: Where should I be making these changes? Sorry I am still new to Assembly.

Comment: Normally, you'd just go off of whatever lines the compiler output referenced. But because the messages don't appear until link time, they don't show line numbers. For starters, you can try replacing all memory references (anything between `[]` brackets) with what I suggested.

Comment: I hate not being able to understand what someone says but I'm honestly lost with all the jargon. If you could please point me to the line numbers of the `asm` file and which change I need to make specifically, that'd be greatly appreciated. This assignment was supposed to help me get started with Assembly programming but it has just made it a nightmare so far.

Comment: Try lines 115, 156, 162, and 311.

Comment: I now get 5 errors like this: `115: error: symbol rip' undefined`, with each one corresponding to the line numbers that you and Ross Ridge  suggested to change.

Comment: @ChrisTarazi just made a fix to my answer - try again?

Comment: *sigh* This why I don't like NASM, it does too many things differently.

Comment: Which one would you have me use?

Comment: @ChrisTarazi alright, I think I've actually got it this time. Turns out NASM uses `rel` instead of `rip`.

Comment: You'd have to pretty much completely rewrite your assembly code to use any other assembler (eg. GAS or MASM) that's not a clone of NASM. So it's not worth it. I was just moaning about how NASM has essentially created a yet another incompatible version of Intel assembly.

Comment: @ChrisTarazi probably better-suited as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `objdump -d` on `avxmain.o` to find out which statements the linker is complaining about. However it's pretty clear which instructions are the problem:

```
xrstor     [backuparea]
vmovupd ymm0, [testdata]  
vmovupd ymm1, [testdata+32] 
xsave      [backuparea]
```

The problem, as Drew McGowen explained, is that the 64-bit instruction set has no way of encoding these addresses a 64-bit values in an instruction. Instead they become 32-bit signed displacements that are signed extended to 64-bits to create the effective address. As apparently Windows loads 64-bit drivers in the address range starting at `` 0xFFFFF88`00000000 `` the truncated 32-bit displacements won't get sign extended back to the correct value.

You should be able to use RIP relative addressing, like Drew McGowen suggested, to work around the problem. In that case the assembler should generate PC relative (RIP relative) relocations that the linker won't complain about:

```
xrstor     [rel backuparea]
vmovupd ymm0, [rel testdata]  
vmovupd ymm1, [rel + testdata+32] 
xsave      [rel backuparea]
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with correct information on where Windows loads 64-bit drivers.